# Wordpress WYSIWYG adding <br> tags

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg

I'm using a Wordpress WySIWYG editor but I'm getting some strange output when I drop for instance a bullet list.

I'm creating the editor using -

```
$settings_editor = array(
         'textarea_rows' => 8,
         'textarea_name' => "editor",
          'media_buttons' => true,
          'quicktags'     => true,
          'tinymce'       => true
);
```

Thats then loaded into a form element using wp_editor then Im outputting the result like this  -

```
<?php echo nl2br($contents_gen); ?>
```

The HTML Output for instance when I drop a bullet list in outputs

```
<ul>
<br>
<li>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks
D

Comment: You are replacing each new line with br, which means new lines everywhere, even in middle of tags.

Comment: I need to wrap my $contents_gen; with something though, as it doesn't accept line breaks at all.

Comment: If you need to wrap it just append and prepend anything you want, but the new lines should come from WYSIWYG, not injected on output.